# How to compare two children nodes from different references in Android Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase I have the "Users" node where I store information about the registered users and I have the "tasks" node with the tasks information created by each user and 3 owners email addresses added to these tasks manually. I am trying to compare the email field from Users with each owners email. If the current user's email is one of the 3 owner emails, then I will show only the tasks where his email is among those.

This is a snippet from my Firebase realtime database:

```
    "Users" : 
       {"SolD4tqjUJd1Xru3mRliwtoik2A3" : 
           { "email" : "x@gmail.com",

             "id" : "SolD4tqjUJd1Xru3mRliwtoik2A3",

            "name" : "AB",

            "phone" : "123456789"
           }
        },


     "tasks" : 
         { "-LgrtyuTjd2QpNIhUeEi" : 
              { "-Lgsjx1c-E6OU3t1SbhL" : 
                   { "id" : "-Lgsjx1c-E6OU3t1SbhL",

                     "owner_one" : "x@gmail.com",

                    "owner_three" : "y@gmail.com",

                    "owner_two" : "z@gmail.com",

                    "projectId" : "-LgrtyuTjd2QpNIhUeEi",

                    "taskDate" : "2019 / 6 / 5",

                    "taskDescription" : "dddd",

                    "taskName" : "ddddd",

                    "taskstatus" : "Closed",

                    "userId" : "SolD4tqjUJd1Xru3mRliwtoik2A3"
                  }
                }
               }
              }
```

I have tried the following code to get the email from Users and the owners emails from tasks, but I get stuck at comparing the email with email1, email2 and email3.

```
        myTasks = findViewById(R.id.myTasks);
        myTasks.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            String email = user.getEmail();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks");
    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){


        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            //set code to retrieve data and replace layout

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Task p;
                p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Task.class);
                String email1 = p.getOwner_one();
                String email2 = p.getOwner_two();
                String email3 = p.getOwner_three();

                tasks.add(p);
            }
            taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(MyTasks.this, tasks);
            myTasks.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
            taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: It can also be more than three users? Why do you have two levels of pushed ids within the `tasks` node? Is it allowed for you to change something your database strutcure?

Comment: In the tasks only 3 users can be added to work on the same task; there are two levels of ids in the tasks node because the first one is the project's id to which the task belongs and the other one is the task's id. What do you advise to change in the database structure?

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a database call in order to be able to get the email address of the user, you can simply get the email address directly from the `FirebaseUser` object like this:

```
String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

According to your database schema, please note that there is no way you can query your database when you have two nodes with dynamically (pushed) names. There are also no wildcards in Firebase. To solve this, you should reduce the number of children by adding the project's id as a property of your task object. Now, to get all task that corresponde to a specific email address, please use the following query:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks");
Query firstQuery = reference.orderByChild("owner_one").equalsTo("x@gmail.com");
```

This works only with one property. Unfortunately, you cannot query in Firebase realtime database using multiple "WHERE" clauses (in SQL terms). What you can do is to query the database three times, once for every owner property. The second and the third query should look like this:

```
Query secondQuery = reference.orderByChild("owner_two").equalsTo("x@gmail.com");
Query thirdQuery = reference.orderByChild("owner_three").equalsTo("x@gmail.com");
```

Please note, that in order to get the desired result, you should use nested queries that might look like this:

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Perform the second query and then the third query
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
firstQuery.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

However, this can be more easily done in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), where you can add a property of type `array` and use [whereArrayContains()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) method like this:

```
tasksRef.whereArrayContains("owners", "x@gmail.com");
```

Comment: I managed to compare the current user's email with the other 3 by following your advice: String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(); and then I used the "if" statement and if one of those three were equal to the current email then only the tasks for that user will be shown. And it works. Thanks  for the input!